# Can you recover a stress tensor from a velocity field?

Tags: physics, vector-analysis, tensors, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

Consider the Cauchy momentum equation for a steady flow:
$$ \rho\mathbf{u}\cdot\nabla\mathbf{u} = \rho\mathbf{g} + \nabla\cdot\mathbf{\sigma} $$
Here, $\mathbf{\sigma}$ is the stress tensor and $\mathbf{u}$ is the velocity field. In $d$ dimensions, the equation may be written in coordinates (and using the summation convention), *viz.*
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \left(\sigma_{ij} + \frac{\rho}{d+1} (g_i x_j + g_j x_i) - \rho u_i u_j \right) = 0. $$
My question is: *Is it possible to recover $\mathbf{\sigma}$ in terms of $\mathbf{u}$?*

This tensor differential equation (TDE) needs to be supplemented with boundary conditions. One is the free-surface boundary condition that $\mathbf{\sigma}\cdot\mathbf{n} = \mathbf{0}$ on a free surface. However, the free surface may form only part of the boundary of a fluid domain, so I think this doesn't fully determine the solution. I think we will need an extra 'normalisation' condition on the total force on the fluid:
$$ \int_V \left( \frac{\partial \sigma_{ij}}{\partial x_j} + \rho g_i \right) \mathrm{d} V = F_i$$
for a prescribed $F_i$.

The TDE is of the form
$$ \frac{\partial S_{ij}}{\partial x_j} = 0 \text{ for } i=1,\dots,d,$$
where $\mathbf{S}$ is a symmetric tensor. Therefore, my question boils down to: *What do solenoidal symmetric tensor fields look like?* For a solenoidal vector field $\bf{u}$, with $\nabla\cdot\mathbf{u} = \partial u_i / \partial x_i = 0$, the Helmholtz decomposition tells us that $\mathbf{u}$ may be written as the curl of a vector potential, $\mathbf{u} = \nabla\times\mathbf{A}$. Hence, regarding each 'column' of the tensor $\mathbf{S}$ as a vector field in its own right, we can write
$$ S_{ij} = \epsilon_{jkl}\frac{\partial A_{il}}{\partial x_k} $$
for a 'tensor potential' $A_{il}$. I don't know what the fact that $S_{ij} = S_{ji}$ means for $A_{il}$.

Comment: To get the stresses from the deformations, or vice versa, one needs to know the *constitutive relations* (i.e., how the stresses relate to the deformation for that particular continuum).  I am not seeing them among what you wrote.

To make it, perhaps, clearer: the same deformations can correspond to different stress loads, depending on the physics of the continuum.  E.g., two springs of different stiffness, stretched the same amount, will be experiencing different stresses.

Comment: Good point, although in the springs example, you can still determine the stress up to a multiplicative constant, which you must determine using extra information such as boundary conditions. 

So that's what my second question is asking. When you invert a differentiation, you get an undetermined constant; when you invert div on a vector field, you get the curl of an undetermined vector potential; what do you get when you invert a divergence of a tensor?

Comment: "in the springs example, you can still determine the stress up to a multiplicative constant"  How would you do it without the constitutive equations?  (For a linearly elastic spring, that's Hooke's law.)